# Why does Kate replace spaces in filename with "%20", thus preventing opening it?

Tags: kate

I'm using the Kate editor ver 16.04.2 on live knoppix 7.7.1 on a usb stick.

When I double-click on a normal text file in pcmanfm, Kate opens but it 
replaces the spaces in the filename with `%20`, and a message says "New", which 
I presume means "new file". The contents of the file I double-clicked on do not 
appear in Kate, but the text window is empty.

Say the true filename is `my notes`, then Kate changes it to `my%20notes`.

If I open Kate separately, then opening the file in the following ways DOES 
work:

- Using File/Open from Kate's menu, and selecting the file from there.
- Clicking and dragging the file from pcmanfm across to the Kate window.

On my main Debian system on the hard drive, Kate opens a double-clicked file 
fine. Why does the double-click opening method replace spaces with `%20`, and how do I fix it?

---

**Edit**:

I did the following tests (on the live knoppix 7.7.1 on usb stick). They may 
help in identifying what the remedy is for my problem.

#### Using pcmanfm

(This is the same scenario I've already described in my original question.)

Kate was already the default application that's launched when a text file is 
double-clicked. I double-clicked the file `my notes` in pcmanfm, but Kate 
opened a NEW file called `my%20notes`, with nothing in it.

While Kate was still open, I did the following to see what filename was passed to Kate:

```
$ ps ax | grep kate
4893 tty5     Sl     0:01 kate -b file:///home/knoppix/my%20notes
```

I changed the default launch application from Kate to KWrite. When I double-clicked `my notes`, KWrite opened a NEW file called `my%20notes`.

I changed the default launch application to Leafpad. When I double-clicked 
`my notes`, Leafpad CORRECTLY opened `my notes`.

#### Using nautilus file manager:

I set the default launch application to Kate. When I double-clicked `my notes`, 
Kate CORRECTLY opened `my notes` (ie no %20 used).

#### Conclusions

It seems to be ONLY pcmanfm (not other file managers, such as nautilus) that 
causes `%20` to be used in Kate. Also it seems to be *KDE* launch applications 
(Kate and KWrite) in which the `%20` problem occurs -- but only via pcmanfm. I
don't think pcmanfm itself is a KDE application.

Comment: I don't know why it replaces it but hex20 is the ascii code for SPACE.

Comment: hint: can you see the full command-line passed to `kate`, if you run the command `ps -ax` in a terminal while `kate` is still running? (Close any existing kate windows before double-clicking the file. The recently started processes will be at the end of the `ps` output).

Comment: you could also check the `.desktop` file for `kate` or `org.kde.kate`, in `/usr/share/applications`, and compare the `Exec=` line with the "field codes" here: https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html

Comment: Based on that `ps` output, `pcmanfm` is passing a URL to `kate` instead of a filename. `%20` is a URL-encoded space, and the `file` protocol lets you access local files -- if you went to `file:///home/knoppix/my%20notes` in a browser it would work. Kate is a text editor and doesn't understand URLs. It's likely that `pcmanfm` is passing URLs regardless of application; it happens that Leafpad can handle them and open the file normally. You need to figure out why `pcmanfm` is using URLs. How are you setting the launch app? You might try a custom command-line and set it to `/usr/bin/kate %f`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the cure!

I'm using the LXDE desktop environment, and did the following to fix the 
problem.

Select the KMenu icon at the left end of the Desktop Panel at the bottom of the 
screen. Select Accessories/MainMenu. When the MainMenu application appears, 
click on Accessories in the left box, then click on Kate in the middle box, then 
click on Properties at the right.

In the "Command" box, replace "kate -b %U" with "kate -b".

When I now double-click a text file in pcmanfm, Kate correctly opens the file,
ie spaces aren't replaced with %20.

I don't have much knowlegde of the percent parameters (like %U), but I've a 
feeling that %U might mean "Treat the argument supplied to Kate as a 
URL" (not as a normal file).

Thanks immensely sourcejedi and Michael Mrozek for putting me on the path to the solution.